# JSON Object - how to get values

Tags: java, android

I have the following

```
  JSONObect {"28":["Mugisha","Christian"]}
```

from a larger JSONArray that I need to be able to translate

```
 {"28":["Mugisha","Christian"]}
```

into an object which has

```
int itemId;
String firstName;
String lastName;
```

How do I go about this?

Comment: You need to understand [How to parse JSON?](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-json-parsing/)

Comment: what is your problem here...?

Comment: the way i see it is that the first quoted dynamic value of (in this case) "28" is the key but because its dynamic i dont know how to parse it to break it down to get the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to parse like this

```
JSONObject job=new JSONObject('your json string');
Iterator itr=job.keys();
while(itr.hasNext())
{
int id=Integer.parseInt(itr.next());
JSONArray jar=job.getJSONArray(id);
String firstName=jar.getString(0);
String lastName=jar.getString(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Don't parse it yourself!** Use the built-in JSONObject class.

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

Then, unless you already have the id somewhere, do something like this:

```
JSONArray names = object.names();
int id = Integer.parseInt(names.get(0));
JSONArray contents = object.getJSONArray(names.get(0));
String firstName = contents.get(0);
String lastName = contents.get(1);
```

Easy. Just iterate over the names if you want to get more than one.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to understand the format of `JSON`
2. You need to learn `Serialization` and `Deserialization`
3. You need something like `GSON` library to parse it back and forth to JSON

Using `GSON`, it is as easy as using `fromJson(String,Class)` to convert it into a `POJO` (Plain Old Java Object) :)

The thing is to understand how to map the JSON classes to Java classes. I am sure you will find a lot of tutorials on it :)

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);

    String usuario= json.getString("usuario");

    int idperon = json.getInt("idperson");

    String nombre = json.getString("nombre");
```